# How can I convert a date string in to a specific date format in javascript

Tags: javascript

Convert date string in  to a specific date format in JavaScript.

I am trying to get this output. Here I will give date format dynamically. It should converted to date object. Here dateString  is a string.

```
var dateString = '03/04/2019';
var format = 'dd/mm/yy';
var dateObject = foramtDate(dateString , foramt)
```

Comment: Here links .. I think this will help you well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1056730/5284695

Comment: I checked above answers. There date object is formatting  to a specific format. Here I have to format date string to date.

Comment: Try MomentJS : https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Zubair V in the question you specifically asked about converting the date from one format to another. Now in your comment you say you just want to make it into a Date object? Please be clear about what you want. Date objects don't have a particular format, formatting only takes place when you convert the date back into a string. If you just want to _parse_ the string into a Date object you can easily Google that, it has been asked 1000 times.

Comment: Perhaps it's just a case of using the wrong word - if you convert a string to a date object, that is _parsing_. If you convert an object back to a string that is _formatting_ . Make sure you search for, and ask about, the correct process.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'm using:

```
// convert string with format 'dd/mm/yy' to Date object
function stringToDate(dateStr) {
    const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("/");
    return new Date(year, month - 1, day);
};
```

It's only for one specific format.

**UPDATE:**

The above script will not work in IE. It uses array destruction which is not supported by the browser. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility)